# TL084 op-amp low noise?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design

I have always known the TL074 as the low noise version of the TL084. I do understand that there are other differences too like originally the TL074 is better for AC, and the TL084 is better for DC. But now as least the Texas instruments specifications PDF the noise specs are basically now the same as the TL074, the 1st page of the TL084 PDF specs says low noise.

link to the PDF: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl081h.pdf

This PDF says last updated July 2021. I am now wondering if now the TL074 and the TL084 are internally the same now? I know Texas Instruments could have decided that they now use the both the same tested IC die and no longer bin them separately.
But though I am not 100% sure, it could be a typo in the updated PDF schematics.

Comment: TI 1992 linear data book shows noise specs TL074 exactly the same as TL084 (18nV/rt(Hz)). Yet TL074 is headlined "Low Noise" while TL084 makes no mention. Internal structure of both is identical.

Comment: Regardless of the difference between these two, 18nV/rtHz is far from "low noise".

Comment: Then I am guessing that the LF347 is also identical to the 074/074 as well, except for the higher current output of the LF347? The LF347 has a higher current output of 31 mA instead of 10mA for the 074/084 and the other specs between the ICs are identical.  So most likely the LF347 is a binned variant of the 074/084.

Comment: A higher current requires larger transistors.

Comment: @CL.  Texas Instruments website uses the same schematic diagram for the IC die, on both the LF347 and the 074/084.  Also other if I check other websites and various other forums, people are saying the chips are basically identical, except for the higher current output of the LF347.

Answer (score 4):

TI [says that the TL074H and TL084H are identical](https://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers-group/amplifiers/f/amplifiers-forum/1019046/tl084h-tl084h-andtl074h-difference).

Older datasheets of the previous-generation TL074 and TL084 devices (without "H") have shown the same noise specification of 18 nV/√Hz for over thirty years, so it's likely that TI ceased to do separate testing for a high-noise version a long time ago. (When the manufacturing process is good enough, binning is no longer cost effective.)